# Block not appearing when giving custom type

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, custom-block

I am trying to nest one block inside another block but the child block isn't showing when I set custom block type.

If I set both blocks as `page/html` then both blocks show fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <mobilemenu_index_index>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="company_mobilemenu/test_page.phtml">
            <block type="page/html" name="company_mobilemmenu" template="company_mobilemenu/menu.phtml" />
        </block>
    </mobilemenu_index_index>
</layout>
```

But when I declare my custom block type so that I can use the custom block methods the block doesn't show.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <mobilemenu_index_index>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="company_mobilemenu/test_page.phtml">
            <block type="mobilemenu/mobilemenublock" name="company_mobilemmenu" template="company_mobilemenu/menu.phtml" />
        </block>
    </mobilemenu_index_index>
</layout>
```

I have made this file: `app/code/local/Company/MobileMenu/Block/MobileMenuBlock.php` that has this contents:

```
<?php
class Company_MobileMenu_Block_MobileMenuBlock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getNestedMenu()
    {
        return 'nested menu goes here';
    }
}
```

In my config.xml I register it like so:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_MobileMenu>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_MobileMenu>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mobilemenu>
                <class>Company_MobileMenu_Block</class>
            </mobilemenu>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mobilemenu>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_MobileMenu</module>
                    <frontName>mobilemenu</frontName>
                </args>
            </mobilemenu>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mobilemenu>
                    <file>company_mobilemenu.xml</file>
                </mobilemenu>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

What am I doing wrong with custom block registration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `type="mobilemenu/mobilemenublock"` to `type="mobilemenu/mobileMenuBlock"`

Comment: You just saved my sanity.  Been checking everything a million times and didn't know about that case convention.  Thank you